# Does the PH67S C-43 (B3) allow overclocking?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, overclocking

so I've recently bought a used PH67s C-43 (B3) motherboard and I am wondering if it supports overclocking because I am currently choosing between the i5-3570k and the i5-3570 (only options for me rn) I can't find anything about my motherboard so I'm hoping y'all could help me. Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Only K series Intel chips officially support overclocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on manual at msi's website for your board - it does support cpu multiplier setting (when cpu supports it), so buying unlocked i5-3570k can be a better choice.